# Why Google map website is acting weird on webview Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-webview

I'm trying to load maps.google.com when user click a button with this url

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=40.702297,-73.796015&daddr=40.73682,-73.989937&mrsp=0,1

[image]

It works as I expected, but when I click [image]
It load only partial of screen(not cover all my screen).

[image]

NOTE: I tried to load the same url in browser of emulator, everything is working fine.

Here is setting for the webview that I used to load a web:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);

    this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebview);


    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);

    webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


    //....follow by normal setup of webview.setWebViewClient
}
```

Comment: I'm still looking help on this problem, anyone can explain why? Thank you

Comment: Hello, I still have this problem. Can anyone try to create a webview and load this link http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=40.702297,-73.796015&daddr=40.73682,-73.989937&mrsp=0,1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. In my webview I used a line of code in order to load Twitter website (without this line it will only load a white screen)

webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");